# Timeouterror the driver failed to open the listening port VBA

Tags: python, excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

When opening an Excel file through Python it gives an error running the macro in VBA related to Selenium.
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi4er.png)
It errors out on the obj.Start "chrome", "" '--For chrome browser replace edge with chrome line of code. However if I close and open the file manually the code runs fine. See below for the start of the VBA code.

```
Public obj As New WebDriver
Public FindBy As New Selenium.By
Public ReportName, myfile, QTime, ChargeSet As String
Option Explicit
Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const cRunWhat = "StartTimer"
Public SetupSht As Worksheet
Public Schedule() As Variant
Public i, FailNbr, col As Integer
Public SuggestionsDiv As Selenium.WebElement
Public keys As New Selenium.keys
Sub StartTimer()
Set obj = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
Dim a, faults As Integer
Dim col As Integer
Dim Initials, Password As Variant
Dim ID_length As Integer
Dim TagsDeleted As Integer
Dim rows As Integer
Dim Today As Date
Dim max As Date
Dim min As Date

     
     'obj.AddArgument "--headless"
     obj.Start "chrome", "" '--For chrome browser replace edge with chrome
     'obj.Window.SetPosition -3000, 0
     obj.Window.SetSize 1500, 1000
     obj.Timeouts.ImplicitWait = 10000
     obj.Get "https://example.com"
```

I've tried multiple ways of opening Excel through Python, xlwings, pyautogui, win32com but they all give the same error. Not sure if this is a reference library issue on VBA side or what. I've confirmed the driver matches my browser version.